# mysql substring repeats same value

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, mysql-workbench

Can you please help me with this?
I have an issue with using substring_index to split the values in a column, I am not interested in the first two values 1/3.

Table name = cc

path (example values below)

1/3/183

```
 `
select 
cc.path,
substring_index(substring_index( cc.path, '/',3),'/',-1)
,

substring_index(substring_index( cc.path, '/',4),'/',-1)
,

substring_index(substring_index( cc.path, '/',5),'/',-1)
from cc
`
```

which gives the output

> 1/3/183  183 183 183
>   . I do not want the 183 to repeat I prefer a blank or 0 when it is not found in the right index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` or . . . perhaps more simply, just add a bunch of slashes to the column:

```
select cc.path,
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(cc.path, '/////'), '/', 3), '/', -1),   
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(cc.path, '/////'), '/', 4), '/', -1),
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(cc.path, '/////'), '/', 5), '/', -1)
from cc;
```

This will return an empty string (`''`), rather than `0` or `NULL`.  If you want a number, then I would just do `+ 0` on the field to convert the value to a number.

Or, if you want 0 as a string:

```
select cc.path,
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(cc.path, '/0/0/0/0/0'), '/', 3), '/', -1),   
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(cc.path, '/0/0/0/0/0'), '/', 4), '/', -1),
       substring_index(substring_index(concat(cc.path, '/0/0/0/0/0'), '/', 5), '/', -1)
from cc;
```